# How should I use google api node js client ?

Tags: node.js, api, google-analytics-api

I'm trying to call GA api in a react/webpack/babel project using google-api-nodejs-client. However it doesn't work. I've got multiple error in my console. On the google-api-nodejs-client GitHub's issues I found the following answers about a similar issue :

> google-api-nodejs-client is not meant to be used in a browser—it won't
>   work. googleapis (google-api-nodejs-client) will work in Node.js.
>   Excluding googleapis from any server-side bundle (just let Node's
>   module system load it for you) is the best option.
>
> To access Google APIs from a browser, please use the Google API Client
>   Library for JavaScript (gapi).

I don't really understand it. Can someone explain this differently ?

thanks.

Comment: It means it is meant for use with `node`. It sounds to me like you are creating a website/web application. This is most likely for security reasons.

Comment: Sorry I'm kind of lost with all this. Right now all I have is a react project with webpack. I'm running it locally. Everything work fine. Is there a chance that I can use this google api nodejs client or not ?